# How do I generate automated parametric curve images on the command line faster?

Tags: python, matplotlib, command-line, drawing, vector-graphics

I have done this with python and matplotlib but I think there must be a faster more sophisticated option. my Python script is slow and cumbersome. I couldn't find anything like imagemagick specific to the task of generating vector images. I have all the maths and algorithms ready but no clear idea what tool I ought to be using to generate thousands of frames efficiently. The code attached here is a simplified version. Is there a faster, graphics dedicated utility best with vector construction? Am I foolish to use python and this slowish library?

[image: From my python script]

-- Molly J

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot()

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [8.0, 8.0]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

ax.set_axis_off()

t = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100000)

# SIMPLIFIED FUNCTIONS
x=np.cos(13. *t) * (2. * np.sin(83. *t)  + 5.)
y=np.sin(13. *t) * (2. * np.sin(83. *t)  + 5.)

ax.plot(x, y, label='parametric curve')
ax.legend()
       
plt.show()
```

Comment: Post the math for one example. Use the math in -fx on Imagemagick 7, where it is faster than on Imagemagick 6 by 2 orders of magnitude.

Comment: It would be better for you to put your math into your post so it can be formatted and also to define your variables and where they come from. Are they values that are specified ahead of time, etc.  As it is, it is hard to understand.

Comment: if your python script doesn't satisfy you, present the script for discussion. -- as far as I can see, this *marginally* image processing. it's drawing/graphics. and it's *marginally* programming, because there appears to be some math involved. -- specify that stuff in SVG. SVG can be animated.

Comment: What is the range of t?  Is it 0 to 1 or 0 to infinite?

Comment: I use AWK in Imagemagick to do my drawing in for example my mandala script at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/mandala/index.php

Comment: There’s nothing about your Python script that will be faster in another language. You can speed it up by reducing the number of points you compute and draw.

Comment: Thank you @CrisLuengo,  I cannot reduce the points as the final functions have many magnitudes of computation (the example above is greatly simplified). Is there no way to directly access the graphics card using some dedicated utility apropos to parametric curves?

Comment: the math in that script is already about as fast as it will get. it's all numpy. there is little room for improvement, at best maybe a factor of two or so. the bottleneck appears to be matplotlib. -- you can either turn this question into "how can I draw these curves faster?", which may get some answers (either showing faster ways involving matplotlib, or presenting alternatives), or you can ask for recommendations, which will not.

Comment: Thank you @ChristophRackwitz, I added the word "faster". My problem is this:  I am humble enough that I knw there are things I don't know AND things I don't know that I don't know. Matplotlib gives me the impression it is a slow substitute for something much more apropriate. But of course, I don't know what. I use python as it is the only language they taught us in fourth grade.